# Regex with customized word boundaries in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using a function called `findlist` to return a list of all the positions of a certain string within a text, with regex to look for word boundaries. But I want to ignore the character `(` and only consider the other word boundaries, so that it will find `split` in `var split` but not in `split(a)`. Is there any way to do this?

```
import re

def findlist(input, place):
    return [m.span() for m in re.finditer(input, place)]

str = '''
var a = 'a b c'
var split = a.split(' ')
'''
instances = findlist(r"\b%s\b" % ('split'), str)

print(instances)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check if there is a `(` after the trailing word boundary with a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\()`:

```
instances = findlist(r"\b{}\b(?!\()".format('split'), s)
                             ^^^^^^
```

The `(?!\()` will trigger after the whole word is found, and if there is a `(` immediately to the right of the found word, the match will be failed.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IVSheI):

```
import re

def findlist(input_data, place):
    return [m.span() for m in re.finditer(input_data, place)]

s = '''
var a = 'a b c'
var split = a.split(' ')
'''
instances = findlist(r"\b{}\b(?!\()".format('split'), s)

print(instances) # => [(21, 26)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to only match if there is a following `(`?

Comment: @RobKwasowski Turn the negative lookahead into a positive one, `(?=\()`.